# How to print out each command argument with echo?

Tags: bash, arguments, echo

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36495940/9013730) ...

> A command is split into an array of strings named arguments. Argument
>   0 is (normally) the command name, argument 1, the first element
>   following the command, and so on.
>
> ```
> $ ls -la /tmp /var/tmp
> arg0 = ls
> arg1 = -la
> arg2 = /tmp
> arg3 = /var/tmp
> ```

Would it be possible to print out each argument ... let say with echo.

I've been using `echo $@` and `echo $0 $1 $2 $3` right after executing `ls -la /tmp /var/tmp` command but didn't really work.

I also tried this without `> /dev/null` but didn't work as well. (I'm getting exactly similar output as below)

```
user@linux:~$ ls -la /tmp /var/tmp > /dev/null 
user@linux:~$ echo $@

user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ ls -la /tmp /var/tmp > /dev/null 
user@linux:~$ echo $0
bash
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ ls -la /tmp /var/tmp > /dev/null 
user@linux:~$ echo $1

user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ ls -la /tmp /var/tmp > /dev/null 
user@linux:~$ echo $0 $1 $2 $3
bash
user@linux:~$
```

**Desired Output**

I'm expecting to see the following output on my terminal screen after executing `ls -la /tmp /var/tmp`

**Input**

`ls -la /tmp /var/tmp`

**Output**

```
arg0 = ls
arg1 = -la
arg2 = /tmp
arg3 = /var/tmp
```

Comment: There's a misunderstanding in the middle here; you start by saying and showing the breakdown of `ls -la /tmp /var/tmp` -- the command and arguments -- but then proceed to show your interactive shell (with its `echo` commands) expecting to see similar argument expansions. But your only commands are the ones you're executing.

Comment: Thanks @JeffSchaller for the comment. I've updated my post

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? You execute a command and the $0 $1, etc arguments exist for that command, but then the command exits, and those parameters are gone. Are you trying to wrap a command and check arguments? Debug something? I'm not sure how to answer in a way that's useful.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I'm just trying to understand previous answer (`ls -la /tmp /var/tmp`) by producing something visible on my screen with echo.

e.g. `arg0 is ls`, `arg1 is -la` and so on

Comment: Since your shell has no arguments, maybe try setting some or writing a script and running it with arguments.

Comment: In shells that provide interactive command history, you may be able to recover the arguments after the fact using the appropriate event and word designators e.g. (in bash) `echo !:1`, `echo !:2` etc.

Comment: @muru, that was the plan. Do you have anything in mind? Btw, I've updated my question to make it clearer (I hope it does)

Comment: Put what you have in a script and see what goes wrong.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate because it really seems to be asking the same thing as your newer question. Please let me know if you feel it is not and is actually a different question. That said, I think you might just be looking for `set -x`. Run `set -x` and then `ls -la /tmp /var/tmp` and you will see the `ls` command split into its arguments as you expect. Run `set +x` to remove this debugging output.

Comment: But here Sabrina is just testing that answer she cites. Jeff points out 16 h ago about the "misunderstanding in the middle". I answered 12 h ago to show what he means. The newer script Q with the "seq" suddenly opens the Q of how to loop and format the args. The interesting effects of $0 that I show are not touched --> not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The echo $0 did output "bash" in your example. This is true, because bash IS running when you are in the shell.

The arguments you want to access are given to the command `ls`. When that returns, and your prompt, the arguments are gone.

After you create a file (a "script") containing the line

```
echo $0 $1 $2
```

and call it by sourcing:

```
. myecho.cmd a b c d
```

...you get:

```
bash a b
```

After you make it an executable (add #! first line, chmod, cp to a path dir) you  call it directly:

```
myecho.cmd a b c d
```

and now $0 is the name of the new command:

```
/usr/local/bin/myecho.cmd a b
```

(I call it .cmd just so it sticks out. just don't call it "echo")