# Print out argument value in for loop

Tags: bash, arguments

This is the script

```
user@linux:~$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq $#`
do
  echo $i
done
user@linux:~$
```

Output

```
user@linux:~$ ./script.sh a b c
1
2
3
user@linux:~$
```

**Desired Output**

I would like to get argument value like this .... and not just the number

```
user@linux:~$ ./script.sh a b c
1 - a
2 - b
3 - c
user@linux:~$
```

Comment: You included the `bash` tag, but gave your script a `.sh` extension, and the syntax of the file looks more like `zsh` (because of the unquoted variable expansions). Which is it?

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas

It's `/bin/bash`. I've updated my script above with shebang

Comment: something got mixed up now, after deleting...the new "sabrina" question was AFTER a ls command at the prompt...anyway....is i=$((i + 1)) the way to increment? And what about $0?

Comment: @sam68 Are you thinking of Sabrina's [earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/528291/117549), which was closed as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: How can a duplicate be older (16h) than the already exisiting Q (11h)? And did you notice the echo $0 produced a "bash" in her output? I answered also that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bsh
#! /bin/sh -
i=1
for arg do
  printf '%2d: %s\n' "$i" "$arg"
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

That is, instead of looping over the indexes, loop over the arguments and increment an index separately.

A few notes on your approach:

- leaving a parameter expansion unquoted in list context has a very special meaning, [you almost never want to do that](/q/68694).
- [`echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data](/q/65803).
- The `` `...` `` form of command substitution should be avoided these days. Use `$(...)` instead.
- Because unquoted command substitution also invokes split+glob, it has to be used with care. Here, you're using the *split* part which means you have a dependency on the current value of `$IFS`. The output of `seq` won't include wildcards, so you won't have a problem with the *glob* part.
- `seq` is not a standard command and not found on all systems. To loop on numbers, it's not the best approach anyway, as that means storing the whole output in memory and split it (resulting in extra copies in memory), and that means running a separate utility in a separate process even though the shell has builtin support for that.
- If you don't put any she-bang (`#! /path/to/interpreter -` first line), the only guarantee that you'll get is that it will be interpreted by a POSIX `sh` shell (in older systems, that could even be a Bourne (non-POSIX) shell), so you need to make sure the syntax you use is POSIX compliant. Even on systems where `sh` is provided by `bash`, not all `bash` extensions are enabled when running as `sh`.

  The code above is POSIX compliant (and would also work in `bash`) but not Bourne compatible (because of the `$((...))` arithmetic expansion syntax which was not available in the Bourne shell). On Solaris 10 and older, you'd need to change the she-bang to `#! /usr/xpg4/bin/sh -` to get a (mostly) POSIX-compliant interpreter

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
do
  echo "$i - ${!i}"
done
```